# Design a bounding box in Rviz using poses information

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I'm trying to draw a bounding box around four poses which are displayed as arrows in Rviz. I looked at using the [Rviz Basic Shapes tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes) but I don't know how to adapt that code so that the box would remain around the poses if the position of the poses changed. From what I can tell, you have to manually set specific values for the vertices of the box in the Basic Shapes tutorial. I need the vertices to be determined from the pose positions.

The poses are output as  `<geometry_msgs/PoseArray>` and represent positions of [Whycon](https://github.com/lrse/whycon) targets tracked using a usb_cam. These targets might have to move around  for the desired application.

Is it possible to create this box?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294054/design-a-bounding-box-in-rviz-using-poses-information/) by [sdorman](https://answers.ros.org/users/34969/sdorman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2018-06-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I figured out how to do this. I used the [Points and Lines tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines) as a reference and used the line strip function of the [Rviz Markers Display types](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker).

```
ros::Publisher marker_pub;
void VisPoseCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseArrayConstPtr& msg)
{
const std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose>& ps = msg->poses;
visualization_msgs::Marker line_strip;
line_strip.header.frame_id = "/whycon";

line_strip.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
line_strip.ns = "lines";
line_strip.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
line_strip.id = 0; //tag id
line_strip.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_STRIP;  //tag type
line_strip.scale.x = 0.05;
line_strip.color.b = 1.0;
line_strip.color.a = 1.0;

geometry_msgs::Point p;
p.x = ps[0].position.x;
p.y = ps[0].position.y;
p.z = ps[0].position.z;
line_strip.points.push_back(p);
```

I repeated the position bit for each of my poses then I subscribed to my poses message.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "VisPose");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

   marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("line_visualization_marker", 10);
  ros::Rate r(100);
  ros::Subscriber pose_sub = n.subscribe<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/whycon/poses", 1, &VisPoseCallback);

  ros::spin();
}
```

This created a box between which moves as the poses change.

---

Originally posted by [sdorman](https://answers.ros.org/users/34969/sdorman/) with karma: 60 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2